# Why na.omit adds a row to empty dataframe?

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a code that was doing something like

```
d <- load a data.frame, possible an empty one...
d <- na.omit(d)
if (NROW(d)>0) {
 do something...
}
```

This appears to be wrong due to the fact that applying `na.omit` to an empty data frame adds a row to it:

```
data.frame()  
data frame with 0 columns and 0 rows

na.omit(data.frame())  
data frame with 0 columns and 1 rows
```

Why na.omit is doing this to me?

Comment: Could you supply some sample data in order to make your problem reproducible?

Comment: @flowla Basically the problem is that `data.frame()` and `na.omit(data.frame())` have different number of rows.

Comment: This (`nrow(na.omit(data.frame())) > nrow(data.frame())` sounds like a bug that should be report to the [R-devel](https://stat.ethz.ch/mailman/listinfo/r-devel) mailing list or `?bug.report`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because `na.omit` has a logical vector `omit` (in its code) that gets set to `FALSE` for those rows to *keep* and `TRUE` for those rows to *remove*.

However, `omit` is initially set to FALSE before checking on your input data.frame as to what rows to remove and update the value of `omit`. Since your input is an empty data.frame, there are no values that are updated and `omit` retains the earlier set FALSE. And then, `na.omit` calls:

```
object[!omit, , drop=FALSE]
```

which in your case is:

```
data.frame()[TRUE, , drop=FALSE]
```

which gives:

```
# data frame with 0 columns and 1 rows
```

---

Here's the code for `na.omit.data.frame` (which can be obtained by doing `getS3method("na.omit", "data.frame")`). The part that is not run for your empty data.frame are commented out.

```
n <- length(object)
omit <- FALSE
vars <- seq_len(n) # equals integer(0) in your case
for (j in vars) { # the loop is not run at all
#     x <- object[[j]]
#     if (!is.atomic(x)) 
#         next
#     x <- is.na(x)
#     d <- dim(x)
#     if (is.null(d) || length(d) != 2L) 
#         omit <- omit | x
#     else for (ii in 1L:d[2L]) omit <- omit | x[, ii]
# }
xx <- object[!omit, , drop = FALSE]
# if (any(omit > 0L)) { # this is also not run
#     temp <- setNames(seq(omit)[omit], attr(object, "row.names")[omit])
#     attr(temp, "class") <- "omit"
#     attr(xx, "na.action") <- temp
# }
xx
```

---

### Solution:

you could use `complete.cases` instead.

```
DF <- data.frame()
DF[complete.cases(DF), ]
# data frame with 0 columns and 0 rows

DF <- data.frame(x=1:2, y=c(2,NA))
DF[complete.cases(DF), ]
#   x y
# 1 1 2
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue is not with (necessarily) with `na.omit`, but rather with indexing a `data.frame` that has no rows.  eg:

```
> DF <- data.frame()
> DF[TRUE, ]
data frame with 0 columns and 1 rows
> DF[1, ]
data frame with 0 columns and 1 rows
> DF
data frame with 0 columns and 0 rows
```

You can't really index a data.frame and get back a 0 row data.frame.

A work around is to use conditional logic:

```
if (!nrow(DF))
  do nothing
else 
  na.omit(DF) ...
```

A better work around is to use @Arun's suggestion

Comment: The first work around will result in a vector and will have all other entries of row from the row with NA.

Comment: @Arun, it will be a vector, yes, but it will have the correct values.  Try, for example, `DF <- data.frame(X=c(1, NA, 2), Y=c(NA, 3, 4))`  Notice that it is using matrix indexing

Comment: I stand corrected, I was expecting a different output from na.omit

Comment: It's alright. `complete.cases` gives back a 0-row data.frame. Please check my answer.